# Any good guides for writing custom Riak SOLR search analyzers?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, riak

In short, I need to search against my Riak buckets via SOLR. The only problem is, is that by default SOLR searches are case-sensitive. After some digging, I see that I need to write a custom SOLR text analyzer schema. Anyone have any good references for writing search analyzer schemas?

And finally, when installing a new schema for an index, is re-indexing all objects in a bucket necessary to show prior results in a search (using new schema)?

Answer (score 0):

RTFM fail.... I swear though, getting to this page was not easy

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/search-schema/#Defining-a-Schema